# jQuery BootStrap load order

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the Bootstrap framework to build a website.

I'm having an issue with loading my custom CSS file. In this file, I override some elements such as navbar color. When the user submits the form, I make an ajax call to a php file and the response from that file is supposed to be loaded onto a modal message.

In order for my custom CSS to take effect, I have to load it after the Bootstrap CSS file. However, when I do this, my jQuery seems to fail and my ajax calls to my php file don't work. When my CSS file is loaded after the Bootstrap CSS file, my modal message opens but is blank, as if my jQuery never went through.

I suspect this has to do with order in which jQuery and Bootstrap are loaded or incompatibility with the versions of each that I am using.

Please advise.

I have included a code snippet below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Activate</title> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>

        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
                function chk(){

                    var opus_Code=document.getElementById('opus_Code').value;
                    var session_Token=document.getElementById('session_Token').value;
                    //var session_Token=<?php echo $session_Token; ?>;
                    var dataString='opus_Code='+ opus_Code + '&session_Token=' + session_Token;

                    $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url: "redeem_Opus.php",
                        data:dataString,
                        cache:false,
                        success:function(html){
                            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(html);

                            $('#msg').html(html);
                            $('#msg').html(response.response_Message);

                            if(response.response_Status == "200"){
                                window.location.href = "activation_Complete_Page.php";
                            }else{
                                $('#msg').html(response.response_Message);
                                $('#login_Redirect_Button').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Okay</button>");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }

                function logout_Chk(){

                    $('#msg').html("Are you sure you want to log out?");
                    $('#login_Redirect_Button').html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Okay</button>");
                }
            </script>
        </head>

<!--Further down in my script-->
<!-- Modal -->
              <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
                <div class='modal-dialog modal-sm'>

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                      <h4 class='modal-title'>Please note:</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body' id='msg'>
                      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                      <div id="login_Redirect_Button"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <!--end Modal-->
```

**UPDATE**

My current workaround is to load my custom css before the Bootstrap css, and then add my styling within the html page, like so:

```
<style>
  .navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(40,40,40,0.8);
   }
</style>
```

But that same styling is not applied if I do it from my css file unless my css file is loaded AFTER the BS css file, which breaks my jQuery calls. :(

**UPDATE 2**
As suggested by a commenter, the issue was in my custom CSS file. Problem solved once I took those bad apples out. Don't copy/paste from web unless you know what it does :)

Comment: Does the Ajax call return the same if you log that? Then most likely your css is broken. Otherwise, your css *should* not harm the JS, can you provide a working snippet?

Comment: How can I log it? And, what snippet shall I provide; of my CSS?

Comment: @randy you were correct!! Thank you for your input. The issue was in my custom CSS file. Problem solved once I took those bad apples out. Lesson to self, don't copy/paste from web unless you know what it does :)

Comment: Just a note; it is Most likely best to add your custom css after the bootstrap css so you override it. Otherwise side effects may present themselves.

Answer (score 1):

CSS can not interact with your Javascript, only with your HTML.

For that reason, if you apply styles to a page, and it seems like that is causing a problem, try to find out where the error is inside your CSS. You can be pretty sure the JS did not change it's behaviour.

**sidenote**
You wanted to know how to log your Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
}).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);      <---
});
```

Then right click in your browser, select `inspect element`, go to console. You can see the output there.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the clarification. It's good to know that CSS and JS do not interact and can't interfere with one another. Logging will also be vital for future reference. Thank you!